# I want to replace zinc oxide with aluminum oxide in a DIY transistor

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors

I want to assemble a DIY transistor from plastic and aluminum oxide. On this site I also found this document:
https://www.andaquartergetsyoucoffee.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/zinc-oxide-experiments-i.pdf

I want to replace zinc oxide with aluminum oxide.
Zinc oxide there serves as the gate of the transistor.
Will the shutter work if zinc oxide is replaced with aluminum oxide?
(I'm new to electronics)

Comment: Aluminum oxide is an insulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aluminum oxide is an insulator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) It has no semiconductor properties at all, as far as I can find.  It is often mentioned that it is used as an insulator in integrated circuits.

[Zinc oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_oxide) is a semiconductor.  It can be used for a lot of things.  As the PDF linked in the question shows, it can be used to make transistors.

You can't replace zinc oxide with aluminum oxide.

You might take a look at this [list of common semiconductor materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_materials) and see if there's one that is available to you that has properties similar to zinc oxide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and advice. I looked at the list
semiconductor: I found carbon there. Can I use it instead of zinc oxide?

Comment: Carbon isn't in the list of semiconductors.

Comment: I have carbon and aluminum.
What can replace zinc oxide?

Comment: Neither carbon nor aluminum can replace zinc.

Comment: You need zinc nitrate and isopropyl alcohol to replicate the zinc oxide FET in the paper you linked.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful replies.